# Hibernate: "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm facing what I think is a simple problem with Hibernate, but can't solve it (Hibernate forums being unreachable certainly doesn't help).

I have a simple class I'd like to persist, but keep getting:

```
SEVERE: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [hibtest.model.Mensagem]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    [ a bunch more ]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    [ a bunch more ]
```

The relevant code for the persisted class is:

```
package hibtest.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Mensagem  {
    protected Long id;

    protected Mensagem() { }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
}

    public Mensagem setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And the actual running code is just plain:

```
SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
    .configure()
    .buildSessionFactory();

{
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Mensagem msg = new Mensagem("YARR!");

    session.save(msg);

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

I tried some "strategies" within the `GeneratedValue` annotation but it just doesn't seem to work. Initializing `id` doesn't help either! (eg `Long id = 20L`).

Could anyone shed some light?

**EDIT 2:** confirmed: messing with`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.XXX)` doesn't solve it

**SOLVED:** recreating the database solved the problem

Comment: What is the source of the Constructor using String ?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted that. Just initializes a String field with the passed value.

Comment: You are using JPA entity classes and Hibernate session calls, can you mix those two?

Comment: How are you generating the IDs on the database side?

Comment: I'd like to leave that to Hibernate

Comment: Actually, the field is defined as auto_increment

Comment: THX ! Never thought about recreating the database was needed when changing the strategies. :-)

Comment: I changed `GenerationType` in `@GeneratedValue` from `IDENTITY` to `AUTO` and it worked for me. Also, you can have auto increment property set in MySQL.

Comment: I faced this issue because I forgot to assign `AUTO_INCREMENT` in my database definition.

Comment: Recreating DB isn't so easy when you have data that you don't want to lose

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Sometimes changes made to the model or to the ORM may not reflect accurately on the database even after an execution of `SchemaUpdate`.

If the error actually seems to lack a sensible explanation, try recreating the database (or at least creating a new one) and scaffolding it with `SchemaExport`.

Comment: In many cases this problem can also be resolved by just dropping the offending table (or tables), assuming that Hibernate is set up to automatically create/manage the DB schema.  To drop tables from a managed schema, `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` is your friend.  Just be sure to `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;` when you're done.

Comment: I got same problem and try with your ans but again got same error what mistake i do i don't know......I am using mysql data base.

Comment: Hi, can you explain please what is :

SchemaUpdate & SchemaExport

Answer (score 72):

If you want MySQL to automatically produce primary keys then you have to tell it when creating the table. You don't have to do this in Oracle.

On the Primary Key you have to include `AUTO_INCREMENT`. See the example below.

```
CREATE TABLE `supplier`  
(  
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL **AUTO_INCREMENT**,  
  `FIRSTNAME` varchar(60) NOT NULL,  
  `SECONDNAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
  `PROPERTYNUM` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `STREETNAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `CITY` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `COUNTY` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `COUNTRY` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `POSTCODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `HomePHONENUM` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `WorkPHONENUM` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `MobilePHONENUM` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `EMAIL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)  
) 

ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here's the Entity

```
package com.keyes.jpa;  

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 * The persistent class for the parkingsupplier database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier")
public class supplier implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  **@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)**
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "CITY")
  private String city;

  @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
  private String country;

  @Column(name = "COUNTY")
  private String county;

  @Column(name = "EMAIL")
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
  private String firstname;

  @Column(name = "HomePHONENUM")
  private BigInteger homePHONENUM;

  @Column(name = "MobilePHONENUM")
  private BigInteger mobilePHONENUM;

  @Column(name = "POSTCODE")
  private String postcode;

  @Column(name = "PROPERTYNUM")
  private String propertynum;

  @Column(name = "SECONDNAME")
  private String secondname;

  @Column(name = "STREETNAME")
  private String streetname;

  @Column(name = "WorkPHONENUM")
  private BigInteger workPHONENUM;

  public supplier()
  {
  }

  public long getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getCity()
  {
    return this.city;
  }

  public void setCity(String city)
  {
    this.city = city;
  }

  public String getCountry()
  {
    return this.country;
  }

  public void setCountry(String country)
  {
    this.country = country;
  }

  public String getCounty()
  {
    return this.county;
  }

  public void setCounty(String county)
  {
    this.county = county;
  }

  public String getEmail()
  {
    return this.email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email)
  {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getFirstname()
  {
    return this.firstname;
  }

  public void setFirstname(String firstname)
  {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }

  public BigInteger getHomePHONENUM()
  {
    return this.homePHONENUM;
  }

  public void setHomePHONENUM(BigInteger homePHONENUM)
  {
    this.homePHONENUM = homePHONENUM;
  }

  public BigInteger getMobilePHONENUM()
  {
    return this.mobilePHONENUM;
  }

  public void setMobilePHONENUM(BigInteger mobilePHONENUM)
  {
    this.mobilePHONENUM = mobilePHONENUM;
  }

  public String getPostcode()
  {
    return this.postcode;
  }

  public void setPostcode(String postcode)
  {
    this.postcode = postcode;
  }

  public String getPropertynum()
  {
    return this.propertynum;
  }

  public void setPropertynum(String propertynum)
  {
    this.propertynum = propertynum;
  }

  public String getSecondname()
  {
    return this.secondname;
  }

  public void setSecondname(String secondname)
  {
    this.secondname = secondname;
  }

  public String getStreetname()
  {
    return this.streetname;
  }

  public void setStreetname(String streetname)
  {
    this.streetname = streetname;
  }

  public BigInteger getWorkPHONENUM()
  {
    return this.workPHONENUM;
  }

  public void setWorkPHONENUM(BigInteger workPHONENUM)
  {
    this.workPHONENUM = workPHONENUM;
  }

}
```

Comment: we need to make primary-key as auto-increment. After making that change, my issue got resolved

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at `GeneratedValue`'s strategy.  It typically looks something like:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Just going to suggest this, try using this instead of .AUTO.

Comment: I have to check it tomorrow, but I'm almost sure that's not going to fix it. I see a lot of ID keys using GenerationType.AUTO. Anyway, I'll make sure to test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 16):

Dropping the table from the database manually and then re-running the application worked for me. In my case table was not created properly(with constraints) I guess.

Comment: Great solution. Didn't think that way. Thanks

Comment: We should do this when we make any changes to Id column or Generation type

Answer (score 15):

you must be using update in your hbm2ddl property. make the changes and update it to Create so that it can create the table.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: It's work for me.  

Hibernate + Derby DB 

`@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;`

And with the value `create` in the `hbm2ddl.auto` property the changes applied in my Database Schema. 

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue. My mistake was i had set the insertable and updatable fileds as false and was trying to set the field in the request. This field is set as NON NULL in DB.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="roles_id",  referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable=false)
@JsonBackReference
private Role role;
```

Later I changed it to - insertable = true, updatable = true

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="roles_id",  referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable=false)
@JsonBackReference
//@JsonIgnore
private Role role;
```

It worked perfectly later.

Comment: updatable is true by default

Answer (score 5):

I came here because of the error message, turns out I had two tables with the same name.

Comment: Same thing somehow happened to me: MySQL workbench showed just one 'user' table, however, after I dropped all tables in the database, it suddenly showed another 'user' table that wasn't visible before...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I found the tutorial [Hibernate One-To-One Mapping Example using Foreign key Annotation](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/hibernate-4-tutorial/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-example-using-foreign-key-annotation.html) and followed it step by step like below:

Create database table with this script:

```
create table ADDRESS (
   id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   street VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   city  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   country  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table STUDENT (
    id            INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name          VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    entering_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    nationality   TEXT NOT NULL, 
    code          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    address_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT student_address FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES ADDRESS (id)   
);
```

Here is the entities with the above tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6832006422622219737L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
}
```

The problem was resolved.

Notice: The primary key must be set to AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 4):

Another suggestion is to check that you use a valid type for the auto-generated field. Remember that it doesn't work with String, but it works with Long:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long id;

@Constraints.Required
public String contents;
```

The above syntax worked for generating tables in MySQL using Hibernate as a JPA 2.0 provider.

Comment: Changing String to Long fixed this for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that is the problem with the table schema. **drop the table** and rerun the application.

Answer (score 2):

**Just add not-null constraint**

I had the same problem. I just added not-null constraint in xml mapping. **It worked**

```
<set name="phone" cascade="all" lazy="false" > 
   <key column="id" not-null="true" />
   <one-to-many class="com.practice.phone"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what is mentioned above, **do not forget** while creating sql table to make the **AUTO INCREMENT** as in this example

```
CREATE TABLE MY_SQL_TABLE (

  USER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  FNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  LNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

When your field is not nullable it requires a default value to be specified on table creation. Recreate a table with AUTO_INCREMENT properly initialized so DB will not require default value since it will generate it by itself and never put NULL there.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
```

);

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Answer (score 1):

I solved it changuing ***@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)*** by ***@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)***

By the way i didn't need to put it to create, just:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete just delete your schema is a really bad suggestion. There is a problem and it's best to find and fix it.

In my case I was using Envers this creates an Audit table for when entries are updated. But this audit table does not get updated itself it seems when the schema updates (At least not ID and it's relationships)

I just eddited the audit tables offending property and done. Everything back to normal.

**To find what the issue is turn the following properties on in application.properties file**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

This will show you what SQL it is trying to executing and hopefully it will provide clarity on real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the Default value for the column id in particular table.if not make it as default

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I was using a join table and all I had with a row id field and two foreign keys.  I don't know the exact caused but I did the following

1. Upgraded MySQL to community 5.5.13
2. Rename the class and table
3. Make sure I had hashcode and equals methods

   ```
   @Entity 
   @Table(name = "USERGROUP")
   public class UserGroupBean implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "USERGROUP_ID")
   private Long usergroup_id;

   @Column(name = "USER_ID")   
   private Long user_id;

   @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
   private Long group_id;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The same exception was thrown if a DB table had an old unremoved column.

For example:
`attribute_id NOT NULL BIGINT(20),` and `attributeId NOT NULL BIGINT(20),`

After removing the not used attribute, in my case **contractId**, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, by mistake I had placed `@Transient` annotation above that particular attribute. In my case this error make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with a `@ManyToMany` relationship.  I had annotated one of the fields in the relationship with `@JoinTable`, I removed that and used the `mappedBy` attribute on @ManyToMany instead.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code and in my case the code below solve the issue. I had not settled the schema properly

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="table"
         ,catalog="databasename"
      )
```

Please try to add  `,catalog="databasename"`  the same as I did.

```
,catalog="databasename"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 
I altered that offending tables and the field "id" in question I made it AUTO_INCREMENT, I still need to figure out why on deployment time it was not making it "AUTO_INCREMENT" so that I have to do it by myself!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<set name="fieldName" cascade="all"> 
   <key column="id" not-null="true" />
   <one-to-many class="com.yourClass"/>
</set>
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `Long` object type to `long` primitive type (if using primitives is ok for you).

I had the same problem and changing type helped me.

Answer (score 0):

"Field 'id' doesn't have a default value" because you didn't declare `GenerationType.IDENTITY` in `GeneratedValue` Annotation.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because sometimes you need to again update/create the database or sometimes if you have added the field in db table but not not entity class then it can not insert any null value or zero so this error came. 
So check both side.Db and Entity class.

Answer (score 0):

i have got such error in GCP cloud sql when model field didn't match correct table field in db.
Example:
when in model field is `fieldName`
table in db should have field `field_name`
Fixing table field name helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem, when I altered the database column type , and did not add auto_increment. After adding back auto_increment in the alter table command  (as in my original table creation) it worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have not added the below property in my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

And added the following annotation to my entity class's Id column:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

And after adding this I have also drop my table manually from datatbase and run my project again that creates a new table with all default constraints for the table.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem during a demo, deleting and re-creating the db solved it for me.

You can do this using

```
drop table sample;
create database sample;
```

Change the name of database from `sample` to your database.

Answer (score -1):

Add a method `hashCode()` to your Entity Bean Class and retry it

Comment: could you please explain why?