# Hibernate doesn't insert foreign key

Tags: hibernate, orm, foreign-keys, mapping, reverse-engineering

I have Many-to-one relationship and when I'm trying to insert a value, the foreigh key is not passed.

Enitnty Country

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="servicedb.dal.domain.Country" table="Country" catalog="DB">
    <composite-id name="id" class="servicedb.dal.domain.CountryId">
        <key-property name="countryCode" type="string">
            <column name="countryCode" length="2" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="localeId" type="int">
            <column name="localeId" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="locale" class="servicedb.dal.domain.Locale" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="localeId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="60" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="cities" table="City" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="countryCode" length="2" not-null="true" />
            <column name="localeId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="servicedb.dal.domain.City" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Entity City

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="servicedb.dal.domain.City" table="City" catalog="DB">
        <composite-id name="id" class="servicedb.dal.domain.CityId">
            <key-property name="id" type="int">
                <column name="id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="localeId" type="int">
                <column name="localeId" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="country" class="servicedb.dal.domain.Country" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="countryCode" length="2" not-null="true" />
            <column name="localeId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="localizedLocations" table="LocalizedLocation" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="cityId" />
                <column name="localeId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="servicedb.dal.domain.LocalizedLocation" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I create the City entity, I'm setting the Country correctly and the countryCode is not null. But the generated query look like the following:

```
insert into Db.City (name, id, localeId) values (?, ?, ?)
```

But it should be:

```
insert into Db.City (name, id, localeId, countryCode) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And the hibernate throws the following exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Field 'countryCode' doesn't have a default value
```

I hope that the provided information is sufficient to understand the cause of the error. If not, please ask specifically for additional information.

I'm also using the eclipse and reveng.xml to reverse engineer the database, so my **hbm** files are auto generated and I'm not using EJB3 annotations.

**EDIT:** Posted the full mapping of the Country and City entities.

Comment: Can you please post the whole mapping of Country and City ?

Comment: @overmeulen I've added the whole mapping of the Country and City.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804514/hibernate-field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value

Comment: @PSR I've already explored that issue, but without success, seems like the problem here is different. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update="false" insert="false"` in the many-to-one of your City mapping applies to both `countryCode` and `localeId`. Since `localeId` is also mapped in your composite-id it is used in the generated queries but that's not the case for `countryCode` ...

Comment: So what is the solution to overcome this problem? Should I create anothe FK (localeId2) to reference the Country table.

Comment: Yes I think that's your best shot