# Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using MySQL with Hibernate and JPA2.

I have the following table, which I would expect to auto generate the `ID` because `AI` (`Auto Increment`) is checked:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `job` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `JOINING_DATE` double NOT NULL,
  `LASTACCESS_DATE` double NOT NULL,
  `PHONE_NUMBER` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MOBILE_NUMBER` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL_ADDRESS` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEX` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `JOB_TITLE` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `JOB_DESCRIPTION` varchar(800) NOT NULL,
  `JOB_DETAILS` varchar(800) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DRIVERS_LICENCE` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVATAR` longblob,
  `TYPE` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=87 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Job.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@XmlRootElement(name = "job")
public class Job extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...
```

**Dao.java**

```
protected T merge(T entity) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    T attached = null;
    if (entity.getId() != null) {
        attached = entityManager.find(entityClass, entity.getId());
    }
    if (attached == null) {
        attached = entityClass.newInstance(); // <= this is executed
    }

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, attached);
    entityManager.merge(attached); // <= ID is null here

    return attached;
}
```

When I try `merge` the table, I get the following error:

> `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value`

Strange thing is this was working earlier, and the Java code has not changed, I did make changes to some other database tables only. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804514/hibernate-field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value) that some people had this problem and fixed it by dropping and importing their database. I did drop the schema and imported it again. But still get the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: I see you're using MySQL, can you right click on the table on the left, copy to clipboard, create statement and paste the content here?

Comment: @Tchopane, thanks for the reply.  Just added the `CREATE STATEMENT` to the description.

Comment: Ok, maybe you should remove that unique constraint on the primary key. Being the primary key already makes this column's values unique.

Comment: And maybe you changed some tables using some of the columns of 'job' as foreign keys, you should check that everything is defined properly in the others tables.

Comment: @Tchopane, thanks I will try that.  Also, I noticed it may be complaining about the FK tables ID that is not Auto Increment. Just checking that too.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. It was not the Job table that had the error, it was a joined table that had ID as null, and it wasn't Auto Incremented. As soon as I set it to AI, it works.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Nice to hear that it works now!