# JPA/Hibernate :sql error 1364 sqlstate hy000 hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a relationship in spring jpa and facing this issue. I am trying to establish relationship between a subuseraccess table and subuservehicleaccess table.
Now a subuser can have access to multiple vehicles and each vehicle will have a set of access privileges for the sub user.(eg: read,write). 
The `private List<SubUserVehicleAccessFeatureList>` property in the first class defines the list of the relation class added later viz `SubUserVehicleAccessFeatureList`.

**Error**
I am trying to insert record in these tables and, while I am getting an error `sql error 1364 sqlstate hy000 hibernate` saying the field `subUserAccessFeatureId` doesn't have a default value.

I tried to debug and the data while saving is all correct. On the contrary if I remove the `@JoinColumn(name = "SUBUSERACCESSFEATUREID"))` annotation from the below property `private List<SubUserVehicleAccessFeatureList>`  it works as expected. As a part of convention, we need to have names without underscores and hibernate generates underscored names by default. 
Referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804514/hibernate-field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value) but didn't find a solution.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBUSERACCESSFEATURELIST")
public class SubUserAccessFeatureList extends TableMetaDataDTO {

/** The sub user access feature id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SUBUSERACCESSFEATUREID")
private Long subUserAccessFeatureId;

/** The sub user id. */
@Column(name = "SUBUSERID")
private Long subUserId;

/** The vehicle id. */
@Column(name = "VEHICLEID")
private Long vehicleId;

/** The vehicle access feature list. */
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "SUBUSERVEHICLEACCESSFEATURELIST", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =
 "SUBUSERACCESSFEATUREID"))
private List<SubUserVehicleAccessFeatureList> vehicleAcccessFeatureList = new ArrayList<SubUserVehicleAccessFeatureList>();

/** The account access feature list. */
@Column(name = "FEATUREID")
@JoinTable(name = "SUBUSERACCOUNTACCESSFEATURELIST", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SUBUSERID"))
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Long> accountAccessFeatureList = new HashSet<Long>();

//Getter setter eliminated
 }
```

The relation class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBUSERVEHICLEACCESSFEATURELIST")
public class SubUserVehicleAccessFeatureList {

/** The sub user vehicle feature id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SUBUSERVEHICLERELATIONID")
private Long subUserVehicleFeatureId;

/** The vehicle id. */
@Column(name = "VEHICLEID")
private Long vehicleId;

/** The feature id. */
@Column(name = "FEATUREID")
@JoinTable(name = "SUBUSERVEHICLERELATIONTABLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SUBUSERVEHICLERELATIONID"))
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Long> featureId = new HashSet<Long>();
 }
```

Comment: Caution Mysql is case sensitive on Linux. Are you running the DB on Linux?

Comment: Yes I am! its an ubuntu machine :P
You mean the name is conflicting with some other id, is it?

Comment: are the tables and fields all uppercase in the DB?

Comment: I am creating tables via the entity classes using spring jpa. The `@column` and `@table` handles the column and table names respectively