# How do I specify a default value for an identity variable in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot User class which always comes up with the error "java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value". I have tried many times to provide a default value, both in the Java class and in the database table, but to no avail. And I have also switched from generation type = auto and = identity, but to no avail. Thank you very much for your help. Here is my Java Class and my Database Table:

```
package com.ykirby.myfbapp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;  
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
  
    
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Value("#{User.id ?: 0}")
    
    private int id = 12345;
    
    @Column(name = "fbuserid")
    private String fbuserid;
    @Column(name = "apttime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date apttime;
    @Column(name = "apttitle")
    private String apttitle;
    @Column(name = "aptaddress")
    private String aptaddress;
    @Column(name = "aptlonglat")
    private String aptlonglat;
    @Column(name = "aptdetails")
    private String aptdetails;
public String getFbuserid() {
    return fbuserid;
}
public void setFbuserid(String fbuserid) {
    this.fbuserid = fbuserid;
}
public Date getApttime() {
    return apttime;
}
public void setApttime(Date apttime) {
    this.apttime = apttime;
}
public String getApttitle() {
    return apttitle;
}
public void setApttitle(String apttitle) {
    this.apttitle = apttitle;
}
public String getAptaddress() {
    return aptaddress;
}
public void setAptaddress(String aptaddress) {
    this.aptaddress = aptaddress;
}
public String getAptlonglat() {
    return aptlonglat;
}
public void setAptlonglat(String aptlonglat) {
    this.aptlonglat = aptlonglat;
}
public String getAptdetails() {
    return aptdetails;
}
public void setAptdetails(String aptdetails) {
    this.aptdetails = aptdetails;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


}
```

[image: My database schema]

Comment: looks very like this: [Hibernate: "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/804514/592355)

Comment: Do not use `java.sql.Timestamp`,use `LocalDateTime` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes in your `User` entity class may sometimes not reflect your DB schema accurately. You can try one of these below solutions:

**1. Update your DB schema manually by adding AUTO_INCREMENT attribute**

```
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**2. Drop the User table in your DB, and rerun the application**

Make sure that `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is set to `create` or `update`. The default is `none` if you are **NOT** using an embedded/in-memory DBs like H2 database.

This configuration of Spring Data JPA will set Hibernate's `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to the setting value. In our case, it is `create` or `update`.

You can read more about this in the below articles and docs.
[Spring Boot reference - Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)
[What are the possible values of the Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto configuration and what do they do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/17901874)

In production, I suggest you not to use this option but instead use a database migration tool like [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.com/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and leave the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` configuration to be `none`.

More reads about this [Hibernate: hbm2ddl.auto=update in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221422/17901874)

Comment: create worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the existing database and re-generate it because sometimes changes done through the model don't reflect properly in the database. While re-generating the database you can scaffolding it with SchemaExport.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
    @Column(name = "apttitle")
    private String apttitle="default";
```

work?